# Advantage of mapping with a async binding vs a component property in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

Is there any advantage or benefit to using a async binding vs just mapping to a concrete object when my service call returns with data for my HTML page?

Here is an example of the two options.

1. Map to a component property

```js
// component
event: any;

// ngOnInit()
this.eventService.getEvent(this.id).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(response => {
  this.event = response;
}, error => {
  console.log(error);
});

// service
getEvent(id: number): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get<any>(this.baseUrl + 'events/' + id);
}
```

```html
<div>{{event.title}}</div>
<div>{{event.date}}</div>
```

2. map to a async binding

```js
// component
event$: Observable<any> = of (undefined);

// ngOnInit
this.event$ = this.eventService.getEvent(this.id).pipe(take(1),
  catchError(error => {
    console.log(error);
    return throwError(error);
  }));

// service
getEvent(id: number): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get<any>(this.baseUrl + 'events/' + id);
}
```

```html
<div>{{(event$ | async).title}}</div>
<div>{{(event$ | async).date}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Async Pipe Method

The async pipe subscribes to an Observable or Promise and returns the latest value it has emitted. When a new value is emitted, the async pipe marks the component to be checked for changes. When the component gets destroyed, the async pipe unsubscribes automatically to avoid potential memory leaks. When the reference of the expression changes, the async pipe automatically unsubscribes from the old Observable or Promise and subscribes to the new one.

1. We use this design when we are using `Onpush` change detection strategy with state management library because change detection works when we get a brand new object.
2. It automatically subscribes and unsubscribes the observable or promise on component destruction.
3. cleaner and more readable as you can have numbers of async subs in the view.

> Subscribe method

1. Here you have to unsubscribe manually, using take will unsubscribe the observable, but what if you need more data from that observable (it limits the data stream).
2. The major advantage for this method is you can run your logic when you receive data and can use that data at multiple places in the component.

We have used both the patterns based on the scenarios which suits well for specific situation.

Note: `async` pipe method needs to get a new reference of the data object passed to it in order to run the change detection and update the view.

Comment: Hi Apoorva. In my scenario, I'm only fetching this data once when the page loads. Based on your explanations, it seems like the first scenario (subscribe scenario) is appropriate?

Comment: How long do you want your component on the view? If you are using it only to fetch data you can use promise? You don't need streams for your work. But to keep things consistent you can use subscribe with take(1), it suits your scenario.

Comment: Hi Apoorva. What do you mean by "How long do you want your component on the view?"